# LMS algorithm for modeling step-size ambiguity!

Tags: matlab, lms

Behrouz Farhang-Boroujeny in his adoptive filters, 2nd ed., p. 155 ,told:

> It is sufficient for stability: `1/(3*tr(R))`.

But his book have attached mfile for modeling:

```
%   Modeling
% Last updated on April 28, 1998
%
itn=input('\n No. of iterations?      ');
sigman2=input('\n Variance of the plant noise?      ');
sigman=sqrt(sigman2);
wo=input('\n Plant impulse response (vector, w_o)?      ');
a=size(wo);
if a(1)<a(2)
   wo=wo';
end

N=input('\n Length of the model (N)?      ');

h=input('\n Coloring filter impulse response (vector, h)?     ');
a=size(h);
if a(1)<a(2)
   h=h';
end

Misad=input('\n Misadjustment (e.g., 0.1 for 10%) ?     ');
mu=Misad/(N*(h'*h));
```

You can see:

```
mu=Misad/(N*(h'*h))
```

And it is not matching to his formula in his book ...
I can't understand where the hell it is coming from?

More information about problem:

Scheme of problem:(Note the source of image is irrelevant to my question, it's only image)

[image: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Guan_Gui/publication/264457158/figure/fig4/AS:281603784888325@1444150982091/Figure-1-System-identification-using-adaptive-algorithm.png]

Core of algorithm: (Note, it is average over `runs` for smooth learning curve)

```
for k=1:runs
    x=filter(h,1,randn(itn,1));% the randn creates input sequence that colorize by filtering through filter with h impulse response
    d=filter(wo,1,x)+sigman*randn(itn,1); % Create desired by sum of noise and y(main plant output)
    w=zeros(N,1);

    for n=N:itn
        xtdl=x(n:-1:n-N+1);
        e=d(n)-w'*xtdl;
        w=w+2*mu*e*xtdl;
        xi(n)=xi(n)+e^2; % Creation of learning curve, gradient(e^2)=-2e(n)x(n)
    end
end
xi=xi/runs;
```

Note: `1/(3*tr(R))` make algorithm unstable ...!!! But without colorizing filter this will converge.

Comment: LMS adaptive filters do have a number of different variants each having a slightly different definition of the step-size parameter as well as tap weight update adjustment. So you they are probably from two different LMS filter definitions. Does it say which LMS type the filter is, if h is input to the filter, then the Matlab code normalizes the step size by dividing the requested misadjustment to the input power hence it could be a variant of NLMS type.

Comment: @Fat32 This is not NLMS, this is general implementation of LMS by this schem:
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Guan_Gui/publication/264457158/figure/fig4/AS:281603784888325@1444150982091/Figure-1-System-identification-using-adaptive-algorithm.png
also additional information added to question ...

Comment: i guess i would need to see the time-domain sample processing equations.  like how the FIR coefficients are updated or adapted.  i don't wanna decode your code, but the bottom looks like vanilla-flavored non-normalized LMS with `2*mu` as the adaptation gain.  i wonder what the `xi(n)` array is for?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson `xi(n)` is Learning curve, isn't that obvious?

Comment: Look! the link you provided shows a block diagram indicating **LMS/F** on the adaptive algorithm being considered. And [http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/585044/]  clearly defines what LMS/F is and its **stability** proprties. So it's probably not standard LMS but a varaint called LMS/F. So you have internet, go read that paper.

Comment: @Fat32 I really interested on your precision! But I serched on google to finding an image, since "stack exchange" deleting images soon ... . Are you still think I'm need to read that? I think that's irrelevant, The code's I called core algorithm tell obviously simple General LMS algorithm, it is. Also  Behrouz in his Adaptive filters book, indicated this ...

Comment: Additionally I looked at that paper, that updating formula is completely different, but with same plant scheme.

Comment: yes your time domain code update clarifies that it's not NLMS, there is no normalization at the tap update stage. I suggest you read books from Haykin, Sayeed, Widrow etc to become more knowledgeable in the field of adaptive filters, especially the adaptive ones. Some authors prefer to use their own notation and may end up in confusion. Selection of step size is the most critial part of LMS and a lot of different approaches exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the first edition of Behrouz Farhang-Boroujeny's Adaptive Filters book.  I found it useful and it was definitely more practical in terms of implementing adaptive filters than other textbooks like those from Haykin and Sayed, primarily because of the included Matlab code.  However, like any topic in the area of adaptive filtering, I would use it with a grain of salt.

There are numerous variations of the LMS algorithm, primarily because it is readily implemented and not computationally expensive compared to other adaptive algorithms such as the Recursive Least Squares (RLS) algorithm.

I think a lot of the LMS variations you can find (particularly in Farhang-Boroujeny's book) come about because people tweak one of the more traditional variations, ending up with something that performs well for their particular problem.  These often make it into journals because they are different and are indeed novel implementations.

I would suggest you read about the standard LMS algorithm and the normalized version of this algorithm, the NLMS.  Once you feel comfortable with your understanding of these algorithms, then implement them and apply them to your problem.  Tuning the step-size can then be done by trial-and-error.  If you are keen to understand the mathematical details of how the step-size is determined, I suggest the [Haykin and Widrow](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471215708.html) textbook.  It has in depth analysis of the convergence behavior of LMS-based algorithms.

Here is an example (my code) of the LMS algorithm in Matlab.

```
function [ prediction_error, weights ] = LMS_Algorithm( regressive_sequence, ...
    step_size, number_of_taps )

% This script-file implements the Least Mean-squares (LMS) adaptive
% algorithm.
%
%
%% See Also
% LMS_Algorithm, NLMS_Algorithm, RLS_Algorithm, APA_Algorithm

% Author:  Michael R. Wirtzfeld
% Modification Date:  Monday, February 27, 2012
% Creation Date:  Wednesday, February 15, 2012


weights = zeros( number_of_taps, size(regressive_sequence, 2) );
prediction_error = zeros( size(regressive_sequence) );


for index = (number_of_taps + 1):1:numel( regressive_sequence )

    tap_inputs = [ regressive_sequence( (index - 1):-1:(index - ...
        number_of_taps) ) ]';

    prediction = weights(:, index)' * tap_inputs;

    prediction_error(index) = regressive_sequence(index) - prediction;

    weights( :, (index+1) ) = weights( :, index ) + ...
        step_size * tap_inputs * prediction_error(index);

end;  % End:  for index = 1:1:numel( regressive_sequence )


weights = weights( :, 1:1:numel( regressive_sequence ) );


%% References

% Section 9.5, Summary of the LMS Algorithm, Adaptive Filter Theory, Third
% Edition, S. Haykin, Prentice Hall, 1996
```

Here is an example of the NLMS algorithm in Matlab.

```
function [ prediction_error, weights ] = NLMS_Algorithm( regressive_sequence, ...
    step_size, number_of_taps )

% This script-file implements the Normalized Least Mean-squares (NLMS)
% adaptive algorithm.
%
%
%% See Also
% LMS_Algorithm, NLMS_Algorithm, RLS_Algorithm, APA_Algorithm

% Author:  Michael R. Wirtzfeld
% Modification Date:  Monday, February 27, 2012
% Creation Date:  Wednesday, February 15, 2012


a = 0.0001;

weights = zeros( number_of_taps, size(regressive_sequence, 2) );
prediction_error = zeros( size(regressive_sequence) );


for index = (number_of_taps + 1):1:numel( regressive_sequence )

    tap_inputs = [ regressive_sequence( (index - 1):-1:(index - ...
        number_of_taps) ) ]';

    prediction = weights( :, index )' * tap_inputs;

    prediction_error(index) = regressive_sequence (index) - prediction;

    normalization_term = a + norm(tap_inputs)^2;

    weights( :, (index+1) ) = weights( :, index ) + ...
        (step_size / normalization_term) * tap_inputs * prediction_error(index);

end;  % End:  for index = 1:1:numel( regressive_sequence )


weights = weights( :, 1:1:numel( regressive_sequence ) );



%% References

% Table 9.2, Summary of the NLMS Algorithm, Adaptive Filter Theory, Third
% Edition, S. Haykin, Prentice Hall, 1996
```

These functions were used as part of an investigation to see how a standard tap-delay line implementation of the LMS and NLMS algorithms could model a second-order auto-regressive sequence.

As Fat32 said, most of the textbooks on the topic of adaptive filters use different notations and suggest different recommendations regarding how to set parameters, so it's no wonder that you feel uncertain about what to do.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I didn't found anything about that Mu calculation even in Haykin, I know `(h'*h)` is tr[R], this is not trouble but `N` is really big trouble. :(

Comment: Furthermore I  had saw this formula in this paper: "Transform Domain LMS Algorithm",6th equation ,but no reference or proofing.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?  It is not clear to me at this point.

Comment: Why `N` is appeared on that formula?

Comment: Your LMS algorithm is for equalizer configuration, not modeling ...

Comment: The inner-product of the system (h) that is used to color the zero-mean, unit variance Gaussian white-noise sequence in the "Modeling.m" example accounts for the scaling of the Gaussian white-noise sequence from unity variance to the variance of the colored sequence.  Since the colored noise sequence functions as the input to the adaptive filter, its variance (i.e. the value of the inner-product of h with itself) is the effective power of the tap-input vector.  I do not know why the N is present in the formula.

I suggest you ask Dr. Farhang-Boroujeny directly.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I can't find his Email on his book. :(

Comment: C'mon, man...  O.o  In this age of Google and vastness of the Internet!?  Try this... http://www.ece.utah.edu/~farhang/